# Android App Php Token Authentication

Tags: android, mysql

I am developing a native android application that will post data to a php page. The php page will then update, delete, insert records into a mysql database. Using the app should be the only time the php page is called from. I have been reading, and it seems that using tokens to validate each request is the way to go. I just really don't understand how to do this from a native android application. Authentication is something I don't have experience in. I want to ensure that using the application is the only way that the php backend can modify the database to prevent outside attacks. Can anyone point me in the right track? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to achieve that is to have some random string stored in the Android application. You have to make sure that this string cannot be easily extracted from the app after decompilation. This can be achieved by using proguard + not storing the entire string in one place in the app (for example you can create a set of methods that can be used to generate that random string). You need to make requests to the server using HTTPS. You can then make the app send this string in every request. Server should successfully respond to the requests that contain this string (for example sent in POST parameter) and return an error for all other requests (you need to implement a check on the server to achieve that).